# Redirecting with JavaScript based on EXACT url

Tags: javascript, redirect, bigcommerce

One of our clients has a BigCommerce store and is looking to redirect users to their home page on login. I used a common solution:

```
<script>
  var referrer =  document.referrer;
  if(referrer.indexOf("login.php") > -1) {          
    window.location.replace("https://www.domainname.com/");
  }
</script>
```

The problem here is that the "Forgot Password" functionality also refers from login.php (it's just login.php?action=reset_password) so users couldn't use the forgot password link. Oops.

What I'm trying to do is either use an exact match of the referrer, or exclude any referring URL that includes "reset_password", which should be very easy but I am very stupid. See below:

```
<script>
  var referrer =  document.referrer;
  if(referrer.indexOf("login.php") > -1 && referrer.indexOf("reset_password") == -1 ) {          
    window.location.replace("https://www.domainname.com/");
  }
</script>
```

What am I missing here? Halp!

Comment: Relying on the referrer is pretty fragile.

Comment: _“What am I missing here?”_ - how unreliable the referrer is, and that it should not be used for something like this in the first place? This should rather be done on the server side to begin with.

Comment: There are browsers that never send referrers along, or the referrer gets lost after the redirect.

Comment: `console.log(referrer, referrer.indexOf("login.php"), referrer.indexOf("reset_password"))` - and then check console to see what the actual referrer was, and which condition was not met

Comment: A few notes: this is not a mission-critical redirect, so if it fails, literally no one cares; the customer gets their account page and not the home page, which is the normal behavior.

Also, this is on BigCommerce, so there's no meaningful access to the server side. Plus, the client doesn't want template changes, which further restricts options.

I'll check the console: good tip! Should have thought to do that to debug.